# using delete_if to find conversations using mailbox and then paginate using kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari, mailboxer

I'm trying a couple things to find conversations where not all messages have been deleted and it's not working.

Here's one implamentation:

```
def index  
    @conversations = @mailbox.conversations.delete_if do |c|
        receipts = c.receipts_for @master
    return (receipts.where(deleted: true).count == receipts.count)  
    end
    @conversations = @conversations.page(params[:page_1]).per(9)
end
```

I've also used .find_each instead of delete_if.

Here's the error I'm getting on my view

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_page?' for nil:NilClass):
```

**Update:** I removed return and now its showing:

NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #):

Comment: What gem are you using for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

The `index` method is exited as soon as it hits `return`

Try removing the `return` keyword.

Edit, re: pagination

When you use `delete_if` the resulting object will be an Array.  Kaminari doesn't work by default with arrays.  See [this link](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object).

So, you would need to do something like this:
`@conversations = Kaminari.paginate_array(@conversations).page(params[:page_1]).per(9)`

A better solution than using `delete_if` would be do put together a query that returns exactly what you want as an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

I'm not sure exactly what that would look like off the top of my head.  Might make a good separate question.

Comment: Ok thanks removed it and now its giving me NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x007fc11e519d70>):